Kung Fu Movie with Large Sword
I saw an old kung fu movie back in college in early 1990's.  The plot from what I remember was of a hero who was avenging a wrong done by a king.  The entire movie was the hero traveling and fighting off being killed in order to finally face the ruler.  One scene, the hero fought another guy in the rain and may have been blinded at the time.  At the end of the movie, the hero encounters the ruler who is sitting on the throne.  The hero throws his large sword which kills the ruler.  At the same time, spears fall from the ceiling, killing the hero.  Does anyone know this film or what the name may be?  It appeared to be in the era of the Shaw Bros films.

Other than the timing and the plot points with the ruler, this seems to match up a bit with Hero, a 2002 movie starring Jet Li.
In the movie, Jet Li's character Nameless, ends up fighting several other fighters who have been attempts on the rulers life.  The movie ends with Jet Li's character "attempting" and intestinally failing to assassinate the ruler.  He then steps outside and it killed with a bunch of arrows.

Hero did have a famous duel in the rain between Jet Li and Donnie Yen reprising their matchups in Once Upon a Time In China, Part 2 but the ending of the film in question would seem to disqualify Hero.

@DukeZhou yeah, I didn't think it a perfect match, but near enough that perhaps 2 movies are being conflated together by accident

The thing about the person blinded in the rain surely made me think of Hero as well (the old man playing the zither.)  I consulted with one of the top Kung Fu movie experts and they couldn't come up with anything based on the descriptions, so possibly the questioner is erroneously recounting the finale...
